# How to repeat a request with updated token?

Tags: flutter, networking, token, flutter-dependencies

I have been using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) for networking in the flutter application. In the request, I am adding token header from the SecureStorage. Now once the token expires(401 error), I refresh the token update the token in SecureStorage. But when the request gets repeated old token is used instead of the new one.

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
     //request for the new token and update it in the SecureStorage.
     //But when the request gets repeated the new updated token is not used. 
     //Same old token is being used

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your interceptRequest function will be triggered again after the shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse function. You should get the new token from the storage in your interceptRequest function and add it to the request

```
data.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = token;
```